# Am I using the correct investment formula?

Tags: self-learning, finance

2. In 25 years, Mack wants to have \$25 000. He plans to invest less than $8000 now. Which of these investment options would allow him to invest the least and still meet his goal? Justify your choice.

A. 4.8%, compounded semi-annually  
$$P=A/(1+r/n)^{nt}$$
$$r= .048, t= 25, n= 2,  A= 25000$$
$$P=25000/(1+(.048/2))^{2\times25}$$
$$P=7637.34$$

B. 4.3%, compounded monthly 
$$P=A/(1+r/n)^{nt}$$
$$r= .043, n= 12, A=25000$$
$$P= 25000/(1+(.043/12))^{12\times25}$$
$$P= 7491.73$$

C. 4.65%, compounded quarterly 
$$P=A/(1+r/n)^{nt}$$
$$r=.0465, n=4, A=25000$$
$$P=25000/(1+(.0465/4))^{4\times25}$$
$$P=7870.18$$

D. 4.25%, compounded weekly  
$$P=A/(1+r/n)^{nt}$$
$$r=.0425,  n=52, A=25000$$
$$P=25000/(1+(.0425/52))^{52\times25}$$
$$P= 8643.52$$

The best option is B as is allows Mark to invest the lowest amount of starting money and reach his goal in 25 years.

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Please try to format it.  See [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to compare the effective annual interest rate $i_n=\left(1+\frac{r^{(n)}}{n}\right)^{n}-1$ and select the highest.

So if $r^{(2)}=4.8\%$, $r^{(12)}=4.3\%$, $r^{(4)}=4.65\%$, $r^{(52)}=4.25\%$ we have
$$i_{52}=4.34\%<i_{12}=4.39\%<i_{4}=4.73\%<i_2=4.86\%$$

and then the correct answer is **$A.\, 4.8\%$, compounded semi-annually**.

Observe that $P=8548.85$ in B and not $7491.73$.